# Why isn't my barplot rearranging properly when faceting with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, bar-chart

So I have made this barplot with this code, bars organised in descending order, great!

[image]

```
 na.omit(insect_tally_native_ranges)%>%
  group_by(native_ranges)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(freq=sum(n))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(native_ranges,freq),y=freq))+
  geom_col(color="#CD4F39",fill="#CD4F39",alpha=0.8)+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x="Native ranges",
       y="Number of invasive insect arrivals",
       title="Species by native ranges")+
  theme_minimal()
```

And now I wanted to do the same but faceting by a variable called `Period`, here's the code:

```
ggplot(native_freq_period,
         aes(y=reorder(native_ranges,freq),x=freq))+
  geom_barh(stat= "identity",
            color="#CD4F39",
            fill="#CD4F39",
            alpha=0.8)+
  labs(x="Native ranges",
       y="Number of invasive insect arrivals",
       title="Species by native ranges")+
  theme_minimal()+
  facet_wrap(~Period)
```

But the plot came out like this:

[image]

Which is pretty annoying because it is the same code as above and the levels for the variable `native_ranges` should be organised again. But instead it gives me this lumpy order that isn't even the alphabetic order. So the `reorder` part is reordering but not by `freq`! Don't understand.

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(native_ranges = structure(c(6L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
11L), .Label = c("Afrotropic", "Afrotropic/Neotropic", "Australasia", 
"Australasia/Neotropic", "Indomalaya", "Nearctic", "Neotropic", 
"Neotropic/Nearctic", "Neotropic/Nearctic/Australasia", "Palearctic", 
"Palearctic/Indomalaya"), class = "factor"), Period = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("1896-1925", "1926-1955", "1956-1985", 
"1986-2018"), class = "factor"), freq = c(21L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 
10L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "native_ranges", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    6:7, 12L, c(4L, 10L), 13L, c(5L, 11L, 14L), c(0L, 9L), c(3L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L), c(8L, 18L), 19L, 1L, c(2L, 20L)), group_sizes = c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), biggest_group_size = 4L, labels = structure(list(
    native_ranges = structure(1:11, .Label = c("Afrotropic", 
    "Afrotropic/Neotropic", "Australasia", "Australasia/Neotropic", 
    "Indomalaya", "Nearctic", "Neotropic", "Neotropic/Nearctic", 
    "Neotropic/Nearctic/Australasia", "Palearctic", "Palearctic/Indomalaya"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame", vars = "native_ranges", drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: I would need the data to give you a complete answer, but I've had this problem in the past.  Basically, `coord_flip` doesn't play nicely with faceting.  Instead reorder your y variable, and then use `geom_barh` from the `ggstance` package. But add your data and I'll show you.

Comment: @BenG Thanks! Sounds promising. So I have adjusted the code applying what you recommended with the `ggstance` package. However, I'm getting the same plot without descending levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally figured it out with help from the other answer.  You need to create another column that summarizes the total frequency so you can then reorder by that column.  There may be a more efficient way to do it, but I create a new summary data.frame and then join it back to the original and then reorder based on the new column.

```
summary_data <- data %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 group_by(native_ranges) %>%
 summarize(total = sum(freq))

data <- data %>%
 left_join(summary_data)

ggplot(data, aes(y = reorder(native_ranges, total),x = freq)) +
 geom_barh(stat= "identity",
           color="#CD4F39",
           fill="#CD4F39",
           alpha=0.8) +
 labs(x="Native ranges",
      y="Number of invasive insect arrivals",
      title="Species by native ranges") +
 theme_minimal()+
 facet_wrap(~Period)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to arrange the order of the variable first before plotting. Since you didn't provide any reproducible data I am using the following data

```
drugs <- data.frame(drug = c("a", "b", "c"), effect = c(4.2, 9.7, 6.1))
ggplot(drugs, aes(drug, effect)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Now to change the order of the variable use `factor`

```
drugs$drug <- factor(drugs$drug,levels = c("b","a","c")) #This is the order I want 
ggplot(drugs, aes(drug, effect)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Here I provided the `levels` in `factor` manually. You can either provide them manually or sort the order of the variable first separately and provide. See below,

```
drugs$drug <- factor(drugs$drug,levels = drugs[order(drugs$effect),]$drug)
ggplot(drugs, aes(drug, effect)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

This should work with `facet_wrap` as well.

Comment: Hi @MaMu, thanks for your comment. In the first plot you can see that I've actually used `reorder` to arrange `native_ranges` by `freq`. My question is more directed at the second plot with the four facets.